# Importing a single large table in Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, import, table, bcp, bacpac

I have an existing DB called `MyDb` in Azure SQL Server.
I have a bacpac of another DB with several tables in it. I'm interested in importing **one single table** (that table has no FK, it makes things easier) into a dedicated table `MyDb.dbo.ImportedTable`. The final goal is to be able to do some data reconstruction using that table.

Problems are:

- `MyDb.dbo.ImportedTable` is ~60 Gb large
- The main column in that table is a `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. That forbids me to use *Elastic queries* in Azure. It times out [since Elastic queries hates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063699/sql-azure-low-performance-of-external-data-table-with-nvarcharmax-column) anything larger than `NVARCHAR(4000)` (I tried)

I guess a good approach is:
 1. Use `BCP` but I only have the binary `*.bcp` files (15'000 of them) that are inside the `bacpac` archive (opened as a zip, in its data folder)

But I'm unable to make it work, especially because I find no documentation about the `*.bcp` file format used in the `bacpac`.

*tl;dr* What is the good approach to import a single ~60Gb table fro ma bacpac in an existing database in azure SQL Server?

Comment: Can you load it to a server on premise then push it to Azure with SSIS?

Comment: I think I could yes. But I would remain with my main question: can I use `.bac` files or how to imprt just a table in an existing Database

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no way to simply use the `.bac` files fomr inside the `.bacpac` archive. 
I had then to revert to `bcp` to  create a text file that will be the source of another `bcp` command to create import the dat in the new DB I want.

To export the data and create the file:

`bcp "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE someColumn = someValue" queryout "${table}.csv" -U $user -P $password -S $server -d $dbSource -N -k`

And then to reimport it as a new table

`bcp [$dbTarget].[dbo].[$table] IN "Fresh${table}.csv" -U $user -P $password -S $server -E -N -k`